# Download file from s3 using AWSSDK.S3 with pause and resume using ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-s3-client

I would like to download a file from s3 with pause and resume functionality using AmazonS3Client.

The code I currently have is:

```
public async Task<IExternalApiResult<Stream>> DownloadFileWithPauseAndResume(string fileUrl, StorageSource source, int chunkNumber)
        {
            const int chunkSize = 1024;
            var bucket = GetBucketName(source);
            var objectName = GetObjectNameFromURL(fileUrl);
            if (objectName == null)
                return Error<Stream>("File URL is not in a valid format for this storage service");

            try
            {
                var request = new GetObjectRequest();
                request.BucketName = bucket;
                request.Key = objectName;

                var start = chunkNumber * chunkSize + 1;
                request.ByteRange = new ByteRange(start, chunkSize);

                var result = await s3.GetObjectAsync(request);
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(result.ResponseStream.Length.ToString());
                return Success(result.ResponseStream);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Error<Stream>(e);
            }
        }
```

Is this method correct? Also how would I trigger the pause method in this and resume method. Aslo should this method be called with a multiplart HttpGet method from the client(Angular)?